# Magento app/etc/modules/*.xml keep re-enabling themselves

Tags: php, xml, magento

After I updated the DB on my staging server with the production database I keep on getting some really mysterious behaviour.
The site was working correctly after the db update.  However, then at 3:49am in the morning a number of the modules xml files in

```
app/etc/modules
```

were changed.   A number of modules which had been set to active = false.  Are now active = true.   I changed these back and as I was using the admin interface.  The same thing happened again this morning.

Also I found a number of new blank xml files for I have never had in dev or production.  These included

```
Mage_Usa.xml Mage_Rule.xml Mage_Rss.xml Mage_Poll.xml Mage_Paygate.xml    Mage_GoogleCheckout.xml Mage_Core.xml
```

Magento must be doing this for some reason.  Which is really strange as I didn't know these xml files could be changed from the Magento app.

I'm on CE 1.7.0.

Has anyone else ever seen this?  or know why this happens?

thanks

Comment: Hi, this is not looking like a magento based behavior. Much more likely is it happens by replacing data / files from backup, or someone changed it manually. try to change permissions on folder /modules/ if it happens again, it should be make impossible for some script to change that again, and in the apache or etc.. log file you can see a log about error during this action.

Comment: those files do not exist on any previous backup. Also they were blank.  I've checked the logs and can't see anything that could have caused it.  Also I've checked my servers access logs and everything looks fine.

Comment: Then someone changed it manually (bad elf :-)), change all passwords to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no chance automatically change database values like above you have mentioned. Some one has changed the your database or may be cron job. Check your **log file** and **cron job** settings .